# How to make an integer equal a char literal value?

Tags: matlab

What I need to  do is set an integer equal to it's char value.

For example, if char is 1, I want the int to be 1, not 49!

The biggest problem is I need to do it to a vector. So I have char vector

```
[ 0 0 0 ]
```

and I want it to become a int vector

```
[ 0 0 0 ]
```

Problem I have is that str2num remove the 0...

To have my exact problem, I pick a line from a matrix and set it equal to a vector:

```
virginMatrix(i,:) = prematrix([positionToPick : (positionToPick + P - 1)]);
```

Comment: Can you show us an actual example where `str2num` removes the `0`? I cannot reproduce that

Comment: @Suever Let me thank you a lot for your time. Sardar_Usama just posted an answer which solved everything!!!

Comment: @Cher See my answer below

Comment: @beaker At first I assumed the string was `'[ 0 0 0]'` as it's written in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be done using [**`num2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), [**`strjoin`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) and [**`str2num`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) as follows:

```
string = [ '0' '0' '0' ];
required = str2num(strjoin(num2cell(string)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want each digit from the string as a number, then just subtract the string `'0'` from each element. This will subtract off the ASCII code for `'0'` from each character in the string and array of numbers representing the digits.

```
string = '000'

out = string - '0';

%   0   0   0
```

This has the added bonus of being the most performant solution since it's just a straight-up subtraction.

Comment: This one is the best, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way you can do this:

Since `str2num` concatenates the rows of the string, you can turn each digit into a single row by transposing the string, converting to digits, and transposing back to a row vector:

```
required = str2num(string.').';

required =

   0   0   0
```